# How to improve nfs io speed

Tags: networking, debian, storage, nfs

NFS server IP is `192.168.99.100`, and 6 NVMe SSD compose a soft RAID 0 array by `mdadm`. NFS client's IP is `192.168.99.101` with 768GB memory, and it connect to NFS server by 40G network. The OS of both are Debian 9.
I use `fio --filename=test_file --name=seqread --rw=read --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=128k --size=100G --runtime=120 --group_reporting --iodepth=64` to test io speed on NFS server, the speed of transmisiion is about 12.1GB/s. And then I mount NFS to client server, and use the same command to test the io speed of NFS, the result is 1.5GB/s. But theoretically the io speed should over 4GB/s.
So I want to konw what limits the io speed of NFS, and how can I adjust it? Thankyou in advance!

Comment: You may be running into the serialization limit .... have you tried with multiple threads?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck Thanks for you comment! I left every thing default when I configured networking and NFS server/client. Where should I check it?

Comment: I ment testing: Use something along the lines of `--numjobs=8 --group_reporting` with `fio`. A single-threaded sequential read test via NFS will most likely be latency/serialization-bound, not bandwidth/storage.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck I use `--numjobs=10` (My CPU is double 10 core), and it even slower then single thread. IO speed only have 900MB/s.

Comment: Are these 900MB/s the group or a single job?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck It's group speed

Comment: The result is `Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=977MiB/s (1025MB/s), 977MiB/s-977MiB/s (1025MB/s-1025MB/s), io=115GiB (123GB), run=120107-120107msec`

Comment: I don't know that you can pass `O_DIRECT` to the NFS server (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259319/2732969). This may mean the I/O is being sent synchronously and you are not achieving the depth hoped for (since there's no full fio output it's impossible to say what depths fio thought it was getting during this drive-by comment)...